# MYSQLI - Select users whom I didn't follow

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I just want a code to select users whom I didn't follow yet.

**members** is a user table and **follow** is the table for follow

**In members table**
id is user's id

**in follow table** there id, user_one and user_two.

user_one is following user_two

so I want SQL to select all users whom I didn't follow, wish someone will help me

Comment: I wish you added what you tried, your sample input and expected output based on the sample input.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try it like this. Change MyID for the actual value.

```
SELECT * FROM members
WHERE
id != MyID
AND id NOT IN (SELECT user_two FROM follow_table WHERE user_one = MyID)
```

Comment: Thank you @Philipp

Comment: Accept/Upvote helpful answers, that's the way to say thank you on this site :) And please read 1000111's comment, helping is a lot easier when you provide some sample data and the expected output (+ you will get upvotes if your question is in a good shape).